# How to specify the text font for specific file types?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know how to set the font family for the editor globally in VS Code.

But I don't know how to change the font for a specific type of file, e.g., `*.txt` with sans serif font.

Is there any way I can change the font for a specific type of file in VS Code?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

VS Code supports [language-specific editor settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings).

In your [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson), you can specify a `[language-type]` and then set the `editor.fontFamily` for that type. For `*.txt` the default and closest `[language-type]` would be `[plaintext]`.

Here's an example for different fonts for *.txt*, *.json*, and *.py*:

```
"[plaintext]": {
    "editor.fontFamily": "Chalkduster"
},
"[python]": {
    "editor.fontFamily": "Menlo"
},
"[json]": {
    "editor.fontFamily": "Helvetica"
},
```

...which gives:

[image: VS Code screenshot of 3 files with different fonts]

To check which `[language-type]` to use for a particular file, open the file, then see the displayed language on the status bar:

[image: VS Code status bar screenshot]